# Room - Got error when inserted row

Tags: android, android-room

This is how I am inserting data into database using Room Persistence Library:

```
@Entity(tableName = "users")
public class ExpParent implements Parent<ExpChild>, Serializable {
@Ignore
private List<ExpChild> mChildrenList;

@Embedded
@SerializedName("UserInfo")
private ExpChild childrenList;

private String UserName;
private String CreationDateTime;
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
@NonNull
private String Id ="";
private String Topic;
//......
```

Data access object:

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao {

@Query("SELECT * FROM users")
List<ExpParent> getAllUsers();

@Insert(onConflict = IGNORE)
Long[] insertAllUsers(List<ExpParent> expParents);
}
```

but when I want to showing number of inserted object into my db I got this error:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.example.sayres.a2_expandrecyandretrofit, PID: 2830
                                             android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x8
                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:312)
                                                 at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:286)
                                                 at com.example.sayres.a2_expandrecyandretrofit.MainActivity$2$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:72)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

this is my way to insert my object into db:

```
           public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, Response<ServerResponse> response) {
            ServerResponse body = response.body();
            final List<ExpParent> users = body.getUsers();
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final Long[] longs = db.userDao().insertAllUsers(users);

                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, longs.length, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            }).start();
```

I am by retrofit, fetch data from my service as a list and then into worker thread I have inserted these data into my db.finally I want to show how number row inserted into my database.but I got error!!!
what is my mistake?

Comment: `Resources$NotFoundException`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are misusing `Toast.makeText()`.
2nd parameter can be either `int` resource ID (example `R.string.some_string`), or a `String`.
You are trying to pass an integer (`longs.length`), which is not a resource ID. To show the integer, you will have to convert it to a string first.

To do that you can for example add an empty string to it:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, longs.length + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```